# Unable to Make a Proper Thymeleaf POST Request with a JavaScript Variable as an HTML input's value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, thymeleaf

I am creating a Spring Boot web application with Thymeleaf as one of my project's technologies. I've created a form in my HTML page which includes a button to save a JavaScript variable. However, I cannot insert that JavaScript Variable into the value attribute of my input tag. I know that my Spring Boot controllers are working fine because every time I click the "Save Top Ten and Location" button, a successful POST request is made. The only problem I am dealing with is properly filling out the "loc_and_rests" datamember of my entry object.

Here is the form I've created (snippet of my HTML): As you can see, I have a checkbox input tag that calls the JavaScript function, changeVal(), when clicked which should change the value attribute of my button in the line to the value of the JavaScript variable, "loc_and_rests," immediately following the input tag.

```
<form name="save" action="#" th:action="@{/app/save-entry}" th:object="${entry}" method="POST">
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="changeVal()">
        <button type="submit" th:field="*{loc_and_rests}" name="submit">Save Top Ten and Location</button>
</form>
```

Here is my JavaScript function, changeVal(). The variable loc_and_rests is a global variable which I set in a different function.

```
function changeVal() {
    document.save.submit.value = loc_and_rests;
    console.log("saved");
}
```

Also, just to show my controllers are working, here is a screenshot of the result of my POST requests. I added question marks and 'x' to some of the entries to see if they would work if I explicitly set a value with the value attribute.

Thank you.

[image: JSON of saved entries]

Comment: How does one click on an _hidden_ input?

Comment: Good point Phil. I hadn't thought about that. I changed the hidden input to a checkbox such that the line with the hidden input is now: ***<input type="checkbox" onclick="changeVal()">*** but it is still not working.